# How to convert UTF-8 string into Chinese?

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8

Here is my code.(python version 3.5)

```
log =os.path.join(sys.path[0],'log')
f=open(log,'r',encoding='utf-8')
s=f.read()
r=s.decode('utf-8')
```

at this point I get the error message.

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

And `log` file may like this:

```
\/div>\n\t<\/div>\n\t<\/div>\n  <!-- <div class=\"search_feedback\">\n  <p>\u6b22\u8fce\u63d0\u4ea4\u5fae\u535a\u641c\u7d22\u4f7f\u7528\u53cd\u9988\uff0c\u8bf7\u76f4\u63a5<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" suda-data=\"key=tblog_search_v4.1&value=weibo_suggest\" node-type=\"suggest\">\u53d1\u8868\u610f\u89c1<\/a>\u6216\u60a8\u53ef\u4ee5\u5173\u6ce8\u840c\u5c0f\u641c<a href=\"http:\/\/weibo.com\/wbsearch\" suda-data=\"key=tblog_search_v4.1&value=weibo_xiaosou\" title=\"\u6b22\u8fce\u8c03\u620f\u6700\u840c\u5b98\u535a\u5c4c\u4e1d~~\">@\u5fae\u535a\u641c\u7d22<\/a>\u83b7\u53d6\u641c\u7d22\u6280\u5de7\u3002<\/p>\n <\/div> -->\n<\/div>"})</script>
<script>STK && STK.pageletM && STK.pageletM.view({"pid":"pl_common_searchHistory","js":["apps\/search_v6\/js\/pl\/common\/searchHistory.js?version=20160324190000"],"css":["appstyle\/searchV45\/css_v6\/pl\/pl_history.css?version=20160324190000"],"html":""})</script>
```

Actually,it's a combination of HTML and UTF-8 characters.When using `exec` I think because it contains a lot of `'`and`"`,interpreter gave an error `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`.

Is there any other way to solve it?

Comment: You can encode a str  in python 3 `s.encode("utf-8")` not decode, the str is unicode already so you just need to print it. What are you doing with the string?

Comment: Thank you,But there are some changes in the problem.

Comment: Out of interest what are you doing with the html?

Comment: It is not really HTML, after the escape of HTML, and in script tags

Comment: As is your code should show the chinsee correctly, where are you running the code from?

Comment: `bytes.decode('unicode_escape'):` is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the file as `bytes/binary`, then use `bytes.decode('unicode_escape')`:

```
>>> b'\\">\\n  <p>\\u6b22\\u8fce\\u63d0\\u4ea4'.decode('unicode_escape')
'">\n  <p>欢迎提交'
```

Thus you could do:

```
log = os.path.join(sys.path[0],'log')
with open(log, 'rb') as f:
     s = f.read()
     print(s.decode('unicode_escape'))
```

---

Also, if you have full Python repr of a string, say `"\u8f6c\u53d1"` (unlike the string in your question), then you can use `ast.literal_eval()`:

```
>>> s = '"\\u8f6c\\u53d1"'
>>> print(s)
"\u8f6c\u53d1"
>>> import ast
>>> u = ast.literal_eval(s)
>>> print(u)
转发
```

Comment: @程书意 the first part that I added after your comment :D `bytes.decode('unicode_escape')`

Comment: Maybe this string is a little bit complicated.

Comment: No, you're using `ast.literal_eval` which was for another possible format that you'd see. I asked you to try `b.decode('unicode_escape')` where `b` is bytes, or possibly `bytes(s, 'ascii').decode('unicode_escape')` where `s` is a `str`.

Comment: Thank you,maybe you're right.But `surrogates not allowed` error occured.I will fix it.

Comment: It would really help to know where this string comes from...

Answer (score 0):

You may find the following info useful.

```
In [25]: s='this sentence with some UTF-8 characters\u8f6c\u53d1'.encode('utf-8')

In [26]: s.decode('utf-8')
Out[26]: 'this sentence with some UTF-8 characters转发'

In [34]: type('this sentence with some UTF-8 characters\u8f6c\u53d1')
Out[34]: builtins.str

In [35]: type('this sentence with some UTF-8 characters\u8f6c\u53d1'.encode('utf-8'))
Out[35]: builtins.bytes

In [36]: type('this sentence with some UTF-8 characters\u8f6c\u53d1'.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8'))
Out[36]: builtins.str
```

I guess `this sentence with some UTF-8 characters\u8f6c\u53d1` is a string that contains unicode code points (ascii is same in unicode) 
I'm not sure if python holds 72 (whatever the unicode code point for A) for A and etc..

Answer (score 0):

Use '#coding:utf8' on the head of program.